# SpringBoot : Setting DataSource "jmx-enabled" is not registering the Datasource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jmx

I am trying to add my data source to JMX by setting the property "jmx-enabled" to true. I have two data sources, therefore the configuration properties are a little different:

```
datasource:
  main:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://chico-testdb1.build.internal\CHICOTEST;selectMethod=cursor;applicationName=omc;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
    username: *
    password: *
    max-active: 150
    jmx-enabled: true
```

I looked at the DataSourceAutoConfiguration class and it appears to only create the MBean when the configuration uses the "spring.datasource" prefix. So I modeled my own configuration after this example:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "datasource.main", name = "jmx-enabled", havingValue="true")
    public Object dataSourceMBean(@Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        if (dataSource instanceof DataSourceProxy) {
            try {
                return ((DataSourceProxy) dataSource).createPool().getJmxPool();
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                logger.warn("Cannot expose DataSource to JMX (could not connect)");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The condition is working perfectly and this method is returning the Jmx connection pool. However, this bean is still not getting registered with the MBeanServer and I am seeing no exceptions in the logs.

I have been able to work around this by explicitly registering the bean with the server but this but I feel like there should be a better way?

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "datasource.main", name = "jmx-enabled", havingValue="true")
    public ConnectionPool getJmxPool(@Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource dataSource, MBeanServer mBeanServer) throws SQLException, InstanceAlreadyExistsException, MBeanRegistrationException, NotCompliantMBeanException, MalformedObjectNameException {
        if (dataSource instanceof DataSourceProxy) {
            ConnectionPool pool = ((DataSourceProxy)dataSource).createPool().getJmxPool();
            mBeanServer.registerMBean(pool, new ObjectName("com.build.jdbc:type="+ dataSource.getClass().getName()+",name=main"));
            return pool;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an inner static class and explicitly depending on the mbeanExporter resolves the issue when using spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "datasource.main", name = "jmx-enabled")
@ConditionalOnClass(DataSourceProxy.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "mainDataSourceMBean")
protected static class TomcatDataSourceJmxConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("mbeanExporter")
    public Object mainDataSourceMBean(@Qualifier("mainDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        if (dataSource instanceof DataSourceProxy) {
            try {
                return ((DataSourceProxy) dataSource).createPool().getJmxPool();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                logger.warn("Cannot expose DataSource to JMX (could not connect)");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```